# How to build a real time iot sever using django rest api and websockets?

Tags: django, websocket, django-rest-framework, iot

I'm building a real time iot server using django and I'm fairly new to django. I have used django REST api so far to get data using HTTP requests, by using JSON. Now I want to further expand my project with the use of django websockets. How can I use websockets with REST api to capture real time data from iot? Or is it even possible to use websockets with REST api.

Comment: a REST API is by definition a synchronous, HTTP API. So it has little to do with websockets itself. But you can combine websockets with django using [django-channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html). You can of course use serialisers and views from DRF to craft the content of your web socket streams, or include updating a channel when responding to a rest call. But they are more or less orthogonal, i.e. one doesn't preclude the other. They're different parts of your application.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. BTW https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HzC_pUhoW0I this video on youtube got me thinking of this notion, where connecting DRF and websockets.

Comment: nice video, interesting. Apparently my remark that rest and websockets are orthogonal is more accurate than the comment rest is synchronous. food for thought :-)

Comment: btw, this is [his code](https://github.com/linuxlewis/channels-api)